# Saving checkboxes in Session PHP

Tags: php, html, session, post, checkbox

i need your help.

I'm trying to save the checkbox values in a session and show, on a second php file.
But the Session is in the second php file always NULL.

If i output the Session and the Post on the one.php, the array looks fine.

one.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Show checkboxes:</h1>

<form action="two.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Boat" checked> I have a boat<br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

$_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['vehicle'];

var_dump($_POST['vehicle']);
echo "</br>";
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
?>
```

two.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$arr = $_SESSION['test'];


var_dump($arr);

foreach($arr as $value)
{
    echo $value;
    echo "</br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Do your `var_dump()`s in `one.php` return/output anything? `$_POST['vehicle']` is not available in `one.php` because you're `POST`ing to `two.php`. (And `</br>` should probably be `<br/>` or `<br>`)

Comment: You right, i dont saw that the post go straight to two.php.
It solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Set `$_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['vehicle']` in page two instead of page one; it's not available in page one. However, you can simply just use `$arr = $_POST['vehicle'];` directly.

Comment: So the only mistery to solve remains "_If i output the Session and the Post on the one.php, the array looks fine._"

Comment: I can solve this mistery.
everytime i checked the Sessionvalue i change the Postscript to one.php

Comment: Well alrighty then

Comment: Thanks all of us to help me so fast.